# Differences between local and remote file system drivers in Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems

Can anyone specify the differences between local and remote file system drivers in Windows? I've read into it but don't really understand the differences.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a odd question. A local system basically tell the OS where to store files. A remote file system is more like a network protocol, since it is sometimes called a network redirector.

So the differences between the two drivers is that they talk to two completely different parts of the the kernel.

Curious, how did this question come up?